# how to set time range in grafana dashboard from text panels

Tags: javascript, angularjs, grafana

I have a scenario where I want to create a text panel in Grafana Dashboard, having some js and HTML. Now I want a way to set time range from that only.

I am aware that to get time range we can use code like below

```
var timeRange = angular.element('grafana-app').injector().get('timeSrv').timeRange();
```

But I want to set time.

Answer (score 5):

```
timeSrv = angular.element('grafana-app').injector().get('timeSrv');
timeSrv.setTime({from: "$date_range_start", to: "$date_range_end"});
```

Got a solution from [here](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/blob/154fbe2413f9abe33157baa563e42fbf67e2f27b/public/app/features/dashboard/timepicker/timepicker.ts#L153)